# Proof that f(z) = $z^{n}(z^*)^{m}$ is not analytic in any point

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, analyticity

Proof that f(z) = $z^{n}(z^*)^{m}$ is not analytic in any point.

If i look at the limit of a more simple function of this form: f(z) = $\frac{z}{z^*}$

I would say that the limit does not exist, because if look at $\lim\limits_{z \to 0} \frac{z}{z^*} = \lim\limits_{z \to 0} \frac{x+iy}{x-iy}$

approach along real axis:
$\lim\limits_{y \to 0} \frac{x+i0}{x-i0} = 1$

approach along im axis:
$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{0+iy}{0-iy} = -1$

these two values are not the same, so the limit does not exist, from which we cam conclude not analytical.

For the original problem there are the exponentials m and n.

$\lim\limits_{x,y \to 0} \frac{(x+iy)^n}{(x-iy)^{-m}}$

As a hint someone said i could use the binomial function(i believe to solve this limit), but am not sure how.

can some one explain this to me?

thanx

Comment: If you already were introduced to them, the Wirtinger derivatives are the most convenient way to prove it.

Comment: Thanx i will look into those, have not heard from them yet tho

Comment: What methods to check analyticity/complex differentiability can you work with?

Comment: So far i only used the Cauchy-Riemann and Laplace equations, but only on simpeler functions, like $f(z)= e^{-x}cos(y)-ie^{-x}sin(y)$ where $u_{x}, u_{y}, v_{x}$ and $v_{y}$ are easy to calculate

Comment: Cauchy-Riemann is doable, but a little tedious. Do you already know that if $f$ and $g$ are complex differentiable in $z_0$, then $f\cdot g$ is also complex differentiable in $z_0$, and if $g(z_0) \neq 0$, then $\frac{f}{g}$ is complex differentiable in $z_0$ too?

Comment: No, i think we haven't come to that yet. But i do find something in my textbook about that, a will take a closer look at that! thanks

Comment: With the above properties, you can see that $f(z) = \frac{z^n}{(z^\ast)^m}$ is differentiable in $z_0 \neq 0$ if and only if $g(z) = (z^\ast)^m$ is. Treating $g$ is much simpler.